# Need succinct overview article about insulin resistance

Tags: health-education, insulin-resistance, pre-diabetes

I need a short article or brochure explaining insulin resistance to give to my son's school.  It shouldn't start with an explanation of beta cells!  It should explain the basic idea about the body still making enough insulin, but how cells don't respond well.  It should explain that IR can lead to pre-diabetes, and it should explain that insulin resistance and pre-diabetes are not exact synonyms.

Everything good I've found so far is too long, e.g. https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/diabetes/types/prediabetes-insulin-resistance

Comment: Hi! I am not sure you will find something about "insulin resistance explained to kids" as even this concept is not even known to many adults. I was wondering: as you seem to have some good knowledge on it, why don't you just make one yourself? Maybe it would be easier. Here an example of how diabetes is explained to kids by the diabetes research institute foundation: http://www.diabetesresearch.org/document.doc?id=274. You could do something similar for insulin resistance. It's just a suggestion. Anyway, good luck, best regards, M. Arrowsmith

Comment: How old is your son and why exactly do you want to make him read such an article?

Comment: @Jan - He is 13.  See next comment.

Comment: @aparente001. Indeed, I misunderstood your purpose. Your description of what the article should achieve and the elements it should not start with (_It shouldn't start with an explanation of beta cells_) made me believe the article was meant for the children of your son's school. Tbh I am still not sure what exactly you were looking for, particularly when I look your answer below. But you have found something, which seems to suit you, and this is the most important thing! Good luck, Best regards. M. Arrowsmith

Comment: @M.Arrowsmith - I wanted something not too technical that the school personnel would understand.  They keep confusing hypoglycemia and insulin resistance.  (They don't see the former occurring and therefore assume he doesn't have IR.)  They also confuse pre-diabetes and IR.  (He doesn't have the former, or the lab values that would go with the former, and therefore they assume he doesn't have IR.)

Answer (score 1):

After massive searching I found a suitable fact sheet.  Its primary focus is diabetes but it includes the basic information I need to get across about insulin resistance.

https://www.cdc.gov/diabetes/pubs/statsreport14/national-diabetes-report-web.pdf

Insulin resistance is explained succinctly, and well, on p. 9.  Also, the difference between the terms "pre-diabetes" and "insulin resistance" is made clear in this fact sheet.  (That is something the school has always been confused about.  They think that because the specialist has not diagnosed pre-diabetes, therefore my son isn't insulin resistant.)

Comment: On this site, is it not the custom to give a reason for a negative vote?

Comment: Hmm... I don't understand the downvote either. Perfectly good answer. +1

Comment: As to your question, explaining downvotes is encouraged but not mandatory. There has been recent discussion about that in meta, which you might want to read.